# Is "C'est pour cela que je suis née" a real quote from Joan of Arc?

Tags: history, quotes

I have found [a very beautiful song](http://journey.wikia.com/wiki/I_Was_Born_For_This), which is part of a soundtrack and numerous people claim that the lyrics consists of several quotes from different people.

One part of it is:

"C'est pour cela que je suis née" which is translated as "I was born for this".

It is said, that this is a quote from Joan of Arc, but when googling the phrase I could only find the lyrics from the song. So it seems to me, that this isn't a real quote because I would rather find the original quote and information about Joan than the lyrics of some song that uses the quote.

Did Joan of Arc really say or write that?

Comment: It sounds like a pretty trivial idiom. And Joan of Arc was most likely illiterate.

Comment: Although she apparently dictated some letters.

Comment: Said by whom?  Is that source notable?

Comment: We have a rule that only widely-held beliefs are in scope for this site (or at least, claims made by notable people and organisations that are widely seen).  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to the song, where people say the song is made of real quotes and particularly where they attribute this to Joan of Arc.

Comment: Please include references to the song itself and where people are saying it is made up of quotes, or else your question is likely to be closed for lacking notability.

Answer (score 10):

According to the book [Procès de réhabilitation de Jeanne d'Arc: raconté et traduit d'après les textes latins officiels, Volume 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=WoVKAvDiQv4C&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=Je+ne+crains+pas+les+gens+de+guerre,+car+j%E2%80%99ai+mon+chemin+tout+aplani&source=bl&ots=m-scNSvWQk&sig=tmt26o4h79WP06RtuBN-f9w2508&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy9fPe0frcAhXrY98KHfy3AiUQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=Je%20ne%20crains%20pas%20les%20gens%20de%20guerre%2C%20car%20j%E2%80%99ai%20mon%20chemin%20tout%20aplani&f=false) (1888) the wheelwright ("le charron") called Henri le Royer (who lodged Joan when she was staying in [Vaucouleurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaucouleurs)) said the following in his deposition:

> Elle répondait: « Je ne crains pas les gens de guerre, car j’ai mon chemin tout aplani; et, s’il se rencontre des hommes d’armes, j’ai Dieu, mon Seigneur, qui saura bien me frayer la route pour aller jusqu’à messire le dauphin. **Je suis née pour ce faire.** »

A rough Google Translate gives:

> She replied: "I do not fear the men of war, for I have my way all flattened; and if there are any men-at-arms, I have God, my Lord, who will know how to make my way to Messire the Dauphin. **I was born to do this.**"

The title of the book says that this is a translation of records which were in Latin, thus explaining why it's a slightly different wording.